# Return results by group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to return the results of each group. What is the correct way to pass each group into a new function?

```
res<-data.frame(ballot1.y=c(1,2,1,2),ans=c(3,5,4,6))%>%group_by(ballot1.y)%>%mutate(res=head(myfunc(.)))

myfunc<-function(vals){
  paste0(vals)
}
```

GOAL

```
GROUP RES
1     3,4
2     5,6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need `summarise` instead of `mutate` and also `paste0` is not doing the intended output.  We need to `collapse`

```
myfunc<-function(vals){
   paste(vals, collapse=",")
}

data.frame(ballot1.y=c(1,2,1,2),ans=c(3,5,4,6))%>%
     group_by(ballot1.y) %>% 
     summarise(res =myfunc(ans))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  ballot1.y   res
#      <dbl> <chr>
#1         1   3,4
#2         2   5,6
```

A convenient function is `toString` which is `paste(., collapse=", ")`